# Find the current node title from my custom module

Tags: 8

I'm working on a simple custom module (Drupal 8). How can I get the title of the current node and use it in module's template twig file (or pass it to twig file through PHP)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it from the route parameters:

```
// Get the node for the current page, if one exists:
if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
  // $node contains the node for the current page.
  $node_title = $node->label();
}
```